# Dhtmlx control form

Tags: combobox, dhtmlx, removeeventlistener

I need help regarding dhtmlX form and combo list controls. I am getting a problem with the dhtmlx combo that created using dhtmlx control. The list of options appears and disappears immediately when clicked on the combo list. The same problem getting with an input box when I click on the input box the mouse focus is removed outside the input box

Answer (score 0):

Unfortuanetly the porblem cannot be reconstructed in the default samples:
https://snippet.dhtmlx.com/wla7u1xq
Please, check if your events are not blocking or closing the combo operating with the input focus.
If the problem still occurs for you please, provide a sample or a code snippet, to check the deatils of your problem.